# select n-th row of certain key SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I select specific number of date (let it be third) for all CustomerID in a row 
for example I have DB looks like

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | EmployeeID | OrderDate  | ShipperID |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   10308 |          2 |          7 | 1996-09-18 |         3 |
|   10365 |          3 |          3 | 1996-11-27 |         2 |
|   10355 |          4 |          6 | 1996-11-15 |         1 |
|   10383 |          4 |          8 | 1996-12-16 |         3 |
|   10278 |          5 |          8 | 1996-08-12 |         2 |
|   10280 |          5 |          2 | 1996-08-14 |         1 |
|   10384 |          5 |          3 | 1996-12-16 |         3 |
|   10265 |          7 |          2 | 1996-07-25 |         1 |
|   10297 |          7 |          5 | 1996-09-04 |         2 |
|   10360 |          7 |          4 | 1996-11-22 |         3 |
|   10436 |          7 |          3 | 1997-02-05 |         2 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

and as the output we have to get

```
╔══╦════════════╦══╦════════════╦══╗
║  ║ CustomerID ║  ║ OrderDate  ║  ║
╠══╬════════════╬══╬════════════╬══╣
║  ║          5 ║  ║ 1996-12-16 ║  ║
║  ║          7 ║  ║ 1996-11-22 ║  ║
╚══╩════════════╩══╩════════════╩══╝
```

something like this

I use MySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Try `select customerid , orderdate from table where customerid = (select unique customerid from table)`

Comment: I Use MySQL, I think, all comands from MySQL work correctly.

Comment: Questions like this are frequently answered. Can you find anything similar?

Comment: I tried to find but was only certain number of row not crtain number of row for each meaning of key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 CustomerIds.CustomerID
 ,(SELECT OrderDate FROM Table1
   WHERE Table1.CustomerID = CustomerIds.CustomerID
   ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) AS OrderDate
FROM
 (SELECT CustomerID 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3) AS CustomerIds;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb4b/6)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
select customerid , orderdate from table where GROUP BY customerid
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want all the columns, then probably the fastest way is to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = CustomerId, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := CustomerId, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table1 t cross join
           (select @c := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by customerId, OrderDate
     ) t
where rn = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simulate `row_number()` in MySQL using variables.  The subquery below calculates `row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by OrderDate)`.  Once you have the row number, it's easy to pick the 3rd:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  @rn := if(@prev_cust = CustomerID, @rn + 1, 1) as rn
        ,       @prev_cust := CustomerID
        ,       Table1.*
        FROM    Table1
        CROSS JOIN
                (
                SELECT  @prev_cust :=0
                ,       @rn := 0
                ) AS InitAlias
        ORDER BY
                CustomerID
        ,       OrderDate
        ) as SubQueryAlias
WHERE   rn = 3
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb4b/34/0)